# Call method from a different activity

Tags: android, methods, android-activity

I have a question regarding calling a method from one activity in a different activity. I have an activity which uses startActivityForResult and gets a result back after the second activity is finished, but before I call finish() on the second activity I want to call A refresh() method in the first activity.

My  initial thought is to pass the first activity as an extra in the intent so I can reference the methods for the activity but can't see how this is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why call `refresh()` on Activity A before finishing Activity B?  If you have started Activity B using `startActivityForResult()` then you will get a result back in `onActivityResult()` within Activity A.  You can then call `refresh()` at that point.  So to give an example:

Activity B has:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

Activity A has:

```
private static final int ACTIVITY_B = 0;
...
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(intent,ACTIVITY_B );
...
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    switch (requestCode){
    case ACTIVITY_B:
        switch (resultCode){
        case RESULT_OK:
            refresh();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can use other result codes to signal other events.